# How to Pass the data from flask if one check box is ticked in front end html?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to flask, How can I pass certain data if a one of three checkbox is clicked in the front end html?
I tried the below code but getting a error : UnboundLocalError: local variable 're' referenced before assignment
my flask code

```py
    @app.route('/output',methods=['POST'])
    def cal():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            cal = request.form.get('c')
            er = request.form.get('C')
            Re = request.form.get('R')
            df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\chana\Downloads\insurance_new.csv")
            if Re:
                tr = 'zz'
            elif er:
                re  = 'rr'
            elif Cal:
                ress = 'zz'
    
        return render_template('result.html',ze = tr, re=re, r = ress

)
```

And my HTML code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Simple tables</title>
    <form method="POST" action="/output" >>
    <div class=page>
      <p>{{re}}</p>
      <p>{{r}}</p>
      <p>{{ze}}</p>
    
    </div>
    </form>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have to make sure that your variables are set in **every** code path and not only if a condition is met. Also consider using more descriptive names. For example the two names `re` and `Re` will cause confusion at some point.

Comment: You cannot return re like this: re=re, when re is inside an if condition (elif in your code). Same goes for r = ress. If the if condition is not met, the variable does not exist.

Comment: @gittert okay noted. so how can I pass value if only one box is ticked? should i use try instead?

Comment: @KlausD. yes I will correct it Thank you

Comment: As Klaus also said the variables are set. What could work here is setting them with re = None right after defining the function.

Comment: @gittert Yes but in the ouput page if re is not selected then it might appear as None in the html page